# What's the difference between CALLBACK and WINAPI?

Tags: windows, winapi

I am learning the winAPI through the docs and I am kind of puzzled by this one thing. The docs use `CALLBACK` and `WINAPI` in the same example and when I tried peeking their definition, they were both defined as `__stdcall`. If both are defined as the same thing, what's the point of having two different definitions for just `__stdcall`?

Also worth noting that while peeking their definitions I also found `APIPRIVATE` and `PASCAL` which were defined as `__stdcall`. What's the point? Can I just replace every instance of those 4 definitions with `__stdcall` or is it problematic?

Comment: Simple answer: Historical and compatibility reasons.

Comment: These days there is no difference.

Comment: Even when the definitions are identical, the different macros are documentation of intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WINAPI` is the decoration used for APIs that Windows exposes to you.

`CALLBACK` is the decoration used for callback functions that you pass to Windows.

Replacing them with `__stdcall` is problematic only insomuch as your code might ever be deemed good enough for other developers to use, who might try and use a gcc, llvm or other compiler that can target Windows, but does not support `__stdcall` as a keyword (except probably does as a backwards compatibility hack because of the number of times reasoning such as the above went unchallenged).

Comment: GCC and LLVM had better support __stdcall, otherwise they'll segfault when calling Windows APIs.

Comment: They support the calling convention, but have a different keyword. iirc in GCC, you would define WINAPI as `__attribute__ ((__stdcall__))` or something like that.